# Texture Paint uv help

Tags: texturing

When i try to  texture paint i can click in one area and it paints in several different areas at the same time like its sharing UV space. How can i fix this. I have tried unwrapping several times with and without manually making seams. I'm not sure of what else to try.[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have multiple UV Maps, and -  in this case - in the material editor add an Input > UV Map Node, choose the correct UV map and plug it into the vector input of the Image you're painting on.

[image]